# Фиксация события клика на iFrame

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, click

Есть `iframe` с видео **youTube**. Необходимо зафиксировать событие нажатия на кнопку `play`, т.е. запустить скрипт в момент когда пользователь запустит видео. Знаю что можно отловить события через `API` Ютуба, но в дальнейшем планируется расширяться на другие плееры, а там с событиями не всегда всё так просто, поэтому и выбрано такое решение.

Пробовал:

1)

```
$('iframe').click(function(e){});  // при клике на фрейме, функция не отрабатывает
```

2) Ставил поверх фрейма `div` исчезающий по клику, с последующей имитацией клика по тем же координатам. Сработал обработчик клика на фрейме, но видео не запустилось

3)

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" onclick="func()"` ... // функция не отработала
```

Возможно, варианты покажутся бредовыми и глупыми, не ругайте, я в [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) ещё начинающий;)

Comment: Так не заработает.

Comment: Я уже понял, спасибо. Я хочу узнать как сделать, чтобы заработало

Comment: Через api - по-другому нельзя.

Comment: Вот и неправда, можно сделать через JQuery, плагин iframeTracker. Уже сам нашёл

Comment: Там жесть какая-то. Почему-то обрабатывает mousemove, как-то манипулирует фокусом, довольно странно использует jQuery. Подозреваю, что он портит навигацию по сайту без использования клавиатуры. И, вероятно, не работает в iOS. А ещё он не сможет определить, что видео запустили, а не просто кликнули что-то ещё.